# Why am I getting the error 400, when the fetch url is ok?

Tags: javascript, fetch

If I access the link in the browser, it returns the expected result *most of the times*.

**Meaning:** Sometimes, when I access the url in the browser I get the 400 error (say, 1 in 7 times), but it's fine after a browser refresh.

Also *sometimes* when it's called with `fetch()`, it throws the 400 error.

I don't understand why and how to fix it.

I am testing the file in the browser, locally.

Should I write the code to fetch again upon failure? Is that a good practice?

Example code:

```
fetch('https://my-url/some-code').then(res => res.json()).then(res => res).catch(error => console.log(error));
// randomNum iteration: expected result
// randomNum iteration: expected result
// randomNum iteration: 400 error
```

Comment: Is your fetch running a GET or POST command?

Comment: The fetch command is GET.

Comment: Its hard or almost impossible to tell because the response you get is entirely dependent on the server. What could be happening is you are making too many request in a short amount of time.

Comment: Your `fetch` call is okay, if the same thing happens in both the browser and when you call `fetch` then there's something wrong with the `API` endpoint - not much you can do about it.

Comment: `400 is a bad request` so something went wrong. Since you do not seem to be sending data, it is probably something on the apis end. Add retry logic into the app and display errors to the user.

Comment: @Aerra do you control the server the API is running on? If so, you should edit in that code to your question.

Comment: @AndrewLohr no, the server the API is running on is out of my control.

Comment: @epascarello is retrying the fetch call upon failure good practice?

Comment: It depends and it is personal opinion if it is a good practice. It really depends on the application and call.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I write the code to fetch again upon failure? Is that a good practice?

Ideally you wouldn't want to call a second request, because there is most likely an underlying problem on your server that is resulting in this response being a 400 code. I don't see any problems with your current fetch request. If you can't fix your endpoint problem however, then just do the second fetch again. If it is only happening 1/7 times then you're only increasing the average workload time by 12.5%, which isn't a huge deal unless this is a heavily used application.

If a refresh on your browser is needed sometimes however, I'd pursue a bit more troubleshooting to make sure it really is your backend. Does the problem not go away unless you refresh? If so, can you access it correctly by opening a separate instance while the other is in need of a refresh? That would point to front-end possibly.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('https://my-url/some-code').then(res => res.json()).(error => console.log(error);
```

removing the next **then()**  and remove **the error which is not in the ( )**

Comment: I edited the post. Meant to write `.catch()`, not `.error()`

Comment: So there is no problem in your code, perhaps in the api url